# SQL Server 2016: SQL Server does not exist or access denied (one client works; 2nd doesn't)

Tags: sql-server

At my 'wits end' here and looking for some help.

I have a Sever (Win Server 2016) running SQL Server 2016.

I have configure one client machine on the network to *successfully* access SQL Server using Ole DB Provider with connection string as:

Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=secret;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=frustrated;Initial Catalog=companydb;Data Source=MySERVER\SQLEXPRESS

Everything is running 'swimmingly' on this client (Windows 7 Ultimate).

The problem is, when I install same code on the 2nd machine and attempt with same connection protocol, I get the following message back from SQL Server:

**[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.**

What I have done/determined as far as troubleshooting...to no avail:

1. Computers one and two are both running Windows 7 Ultimate O/S
2. I lowered UAC to 'Never'.
3. Enable access to port 1433 specifically to the Server Firewall.
4. I disabled the Firewall completely on the Server to see if that was the issue.
5. Established an alternate SQL Server user and attached them to the target database

This is driving me crazy. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Are you able to connect using SSMS from the same machine? That may be an easy place to start troubleshooting.

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for the reply.  I would have responded earlier, but I think I may have had my notifications off. Interesting, are you suggesting that I install Server Management Studio only on the client machine that I am having trouble with? Then, try to make the connection to Server that actually hosts the database? Might a connection attempt using this approach provide more detail in the exception? Thanks, Scott.